# Why aren't form submissions being added to my CSV file?

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to create a form where someone inputs a name (non-mandatory), an email address, and a list of school subjects (non-mandatory). For some reason if all the checks are satisfied (name is all letters or whitespace if entered, email is valid and complete), the submission is still not being added to my CSV file.

Here's the code:

```html
<?php
$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subjects = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = clean_text($_POST("user_name"));
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
        }
    if(empty($_POST["user_mail"])) {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
    } else {
        $email = clean_text($_POST["user_mail"]);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
        }
    }
    $subjects = clean_text($_POST["user_subjects"]);
    
    if($error == ''){
        $file_open = fopen("data.csv", a);
        $num_rows = count(file("data.csv"));
        if($num_rows > 1) {
            $num_rows = ($num_rows - 1) + 1; //Generates serial number
        }
        $form_data = array(
            'serial_num' => $num_rows,
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'subjects' => $subjects
        );
        fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
        $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you for contacting us</label>';
        $name = '';
        $email = '';
        $subjects = '';
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            
            
            form {
                /* Just to center the form on the page */
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 400px;
                /* To see the outline of the form */
                padding: 1em;
                border: 1px solid #CCC;
                border-radius: 1em;
            }
            
            form div + div {
                margin-top: 1em;
            }
            
            label {
            /* To make sure that all labels have the same size and are properly aligned */
            display: inline-block;
            width: 120px;
            text-align: right;
            }
            
            input, textarea {
                /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
                By default, textareas have a monospace font */
                font: 1em sans-serif;

                /* To give the same size to all text fields */
                width: 250px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                /* To harmonize the look & feel of text field border */
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
            
            input:focus, textarea:focus {
            /* To give a little highlight on active elements */
            border-color: #1fb;
            }
            
            textarea {
            /* To properly align multiline text fields with their labels */
            vertical-align: top;
                
            /* To remove resizability feature */
            resize: none;

            /* To give enough room to type some text */
            height: 5em;
            }
            
            .button {
            /* To position the buttons to the same position of the text fields */
            padding-left: 120px; /* same size as the label elements */
            }
            
            button {
            /* This extra margin represent roughly the same space as the space
            between the labels and their text fields */
            margin-left: .5em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
  <div>
    <?php echo $error; ?>
    <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="name" id="namelabel">(Optional) Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="msg">(Optional) Requested Subjects:</label>
    <textarea id="msg" name="user_subjects" value="<?php echo $subjects; ?>"></textarea>
  </div>
    <div class="button">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$file_open = fopen("data.csv", a)` => `$file_open = fopen("data.csv", 'a')`

Comment: `$num_rows = ($num_rows - 1) + 1` why?

Comment: `$form_data = array(
            'serial_num' => $num_rows,
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'subjects' => $subjects
        );` I'm not sure if fputcsv supports arrays with non numeric keys. Aren't there any error messages in the log files?

Comment: @kuh-chan to generate a serial number is what the tutorial said, not sure to be honest with you, I also added the single quotes and got the same error. Changed the keys to numeric and still the same issue. Had the numbers in and out of quotes, both times didn't work.

Comment: oh.... and... `clean_text($_POST("user_name"))` You try to call `$_POST` as a function. change that to `clean_text($_POST['user_name'])`

Comment: The `$num_rows` part is useless as `number - 1 + 1 === number`

Comment: Removed the `$numrows` part and fixed the usage of `clean_text($_POST("user_name"))` but still not saving to CSV for some reason.

Comment: can you post your updated code?

Comment: by the way... did you check your `$_POST` variable?

Comment: What do you mean by checking `$_POST` variable? Also, after I enter data, and I try to refresh I get a 'Confirm form resubmission' message from chrome saying: "The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?"

Comment: Here is the new code: https://pastebin.com/HfCVe9mc

Comment: insert a `var_dump($_POST)` in line 15. I don't think that `$_POST['submit']` is set.

Comment: I added that and now `$error` is always printing and the text is: `array(3) { ["user_mail"]=> string(15) "email@gmail.com" ["user_name"]=> string(10) "First Last" ["user_subjects"]=> string(7) "Subject" }`

Comment: Prior to any submission the message reads `array(0) { }` not sure how or why it is printing the array

Comment: change `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` to `<button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>` You test for the key `submit`. But you don't have an input with this name

Comment: Ok, so now the error or success message is popping up which is great, however it is still not printing to the CSV, and the array is still being printed at the top of the page. Let me know if you want the updated code.

Comment: remove the `var_dump($_POST)` and the array won't be printed anymore. check if the file you are checking is the correct file. The code inserting the data into the csv works, just checked it

Comment: https://imgur.com/sue602W this is my directory, only those two files